# Can't call class method on second Thread - IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, web-services, concurrency

Okay, thank you in advance.

I am utilizing a web service (with xml <-- Irrelevant probably), and I can properly call any function from my code to gather results, or push parameters to the WS.

```
service = [HiphopHipHopGameService service];
    [service GetPlayerImage:self action:@selector(GetPlayerImageHandler:) PlayerID: @"player id"];
```

However, for efficiency purposes, I am attempting to call these same "class methods" on a concurrent second thread. I am implementing the thread usage correctly because, I am placing NSLogs within the new thread, and they are executing correctly. However, if I place the WS methods within the new threads, they are ignored.

I tried the following two ways. Both are working fine with NSlogs in them, but the WS calls are not made.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getopps) withObject:service];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getopps) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the web service calls work?  Synchronous vs. asynchronous?  Are you creating an `NSRunLoop` for the service on a background thread?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's in the `getopps` method or how you're detecting that methods are being "ignored".  (Also, the meaning of "ignored" isn't obvious...either it's being called with a valid receiver or it's not.)

Comment: OKAY good questions, let me elaborate.. 
@NSBURN i believe they are synchronous, because whenever I call one of the methods, the app is still running, and it returns the results whenever they arrive. I then write to nslog to see them for now.

Phil In the getopps is:

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 // Returns NSMutableArray*. 
 [service GetOpponentList:self action:@selector(GetOpponentListHandler:) Player1ID: @""];
 
 NSLog(@"got the opponents");
 
 [pool release];

This is just a temp method to get this to work. It's logging, but the method isn't called

Comment: PS I even tried GCD, and got the NSlog to work, but once again the thread just won't execute the method

Comment: Maybe I'm slow this morning.  :)  If you're seeing a log message, which method is the one not being executed?

Comment: The [service GetPlayerImage:self action:@selector(GetPlayerImageHandler:) PlayerID: @"player id"]; Method is the one not being called Phil.

Comment: Try logging the value of `service` when that call is made.  If it looks reasonable, put a breakpoint on the call and try to step into the method.

Comment: Yea it doesn't log within the method, I already have logs within it. none of them show up. So the obvious problem is that the method itself isn't being called. The app isn't crashing though, it just skips over it. I need to call these methods, and wait for them to return.

Comment: @Jovi It sounds like you've diagnosed a different problem, but when I hear "background thread/queue" and "no response from web service", I wonder about how the data is being requested from the web service. When you submit a simple `connectionWithRequest` for `NSURLConnection` on a queue other than the main queue, the delegate methods never get called. Plenty of options work on background queue, but not `connectionWithRequest`.

Comment: @Jovi - I understand that the method isn't being executed.  What you need to do is look at the caller.  (Which is why I suggested logging `service`.  If a receiver for a message has been set to `nil` it will look as if the method is being skipped.)